# MongoDB: mongoimport loses connection when importing big files

Tags: mongodb

I have some trouble importing a JSON file to a local MongoDB instance. The JSON was generated using `mongoexport` and looks like this. No arrays, no hardcore nesting:

```
{"_created":{"$date":"2015-10-20T12:46:25.000Z"},"_etag":"7fab35685eea8d8097656092961d3a9cfe46ffbc","_id":{"$oid":"562637a14e0c9836e0821a5e"},"_updated":{"$date":"2015-10-20T12:46:25.000Z"},"body":"base64 encoded string","sender":"mail@mail.com","type":"answer"}
{"_created":{"$date":"2015-10-20T12:46:25.000Z"},"_etag":"7fab35685eea8d8097656092961d3a9cfe46ffbc","_id":{"$oid":"562637a14e0c9836e0821a5e"},"_updated":{"$date":"2015-10-20T12:46:25.000Z"},"body":"base64 encoded string","sender":"mail@mail.com","type":"answer"}
```

If I import a 9MB file with ~300 rows, there is no problem:

```
[stekhn latest]$ mongoimport -d mietscraping -c mails mails-small.json 
2015-11-02T10:03:11.353+0100    connected to: localhost
2015-11-02T10:03:11.372+0100    imported 240 documents
```

But if try to import a 32MB file with ~1300 rows, the import fails:

```
[stekhn latest]$ mongoimport -d mietscraping -c mails mails.json 
2015-11-02T10:05:25.228+0100    connected to: localhost
2015-11-02T10:05:25.735+0100    error inserting documents: lost connection to server
2015-11-02T10:05:25.735+0100    Failed: lost connection to server
2015-11-02T10:05:25.735+0100    imported 0 documents
```

Here is the log:

```
2015-11-02T11:53:04.146+0100 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45237 #21 (6 connections now open)
2015-11-02T11:53:04.532+0100 I -        [conn21] Assertion: 10334:BSONObj size: 23592351 (0x167FD9F) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: insert: "mails"
2015-11-02T11:53:04.536+0100 I NETWORK  [conn21] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 10334 BSONObj size: 23592351 (0x167FD9F) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: insert: "mails"
```

I've heard about the [16MB limit for BSON documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/) before, but since no row in my JSON file is bigger than 16MB, this shouldn't be a problem, right? When I do the exact same (32MB) import one my local computer, everything works fine.

Any ideas what could cause this weird behaviour?

Comment: Probably worth posting the logs from the instance from around the timestamp where the connection was lost (it really could be anything based on the output above).

Comment: try this if it makes difference: `mongoimport -d mietscraping -c mails < mails.json`

Comment: do you use `mongoexport` to export your mails.json ?

Comment: Yes, I use mongoexport and no, unfortunatelly `mails < mails.json` returns the same error.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I guess the problem is about performance, any way you can solved used:

you can use **mongoimport option -j**. Try increment if not work with 4. i.e, 4,8,16, depend of the number of core you have in your cpu.

mongoimport --help

-j, --numInsertionWorkers=         number of insert operations to run
                                     concurrently (defaults to 1)

---

**mongoimport -d mietscraping -c mails -j 4 < mails.json**

---

**or you can split the file and import all files.**

I hope this help you.

---

looking a little more, is a bug in some version
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-939
here another solution you can change the batchSize, for default is 10000, reduce the value and test:

**mongoimport -d mietscraping -c mails < mails.json --batchSize 1**

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick and also works for 10.000+ documents.

Comment: It should be noted that --batchSize seems to be undocumented (it isn't in the mongoimport --help output for my mongo version, 3.0.10).

Answer (score 0):

Quite old, but I struggled on same issue.
If you want to import big files, especially remote with Compass or by Program just add

```
&wtimeoutMS=0
```

to your Connection-String. This removes Timeout on Write-Operations.

Comment: This is a connection string option, in order to use it you will need to specify aslo the `--uri=<connectionString>` with the `mongoimport` options