# Connection error while mongorestore

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to import some data in mongodb using :

```
 mongoimport -d blog -c posts < posts.json
```

But start to get this error :

```
2015-11-06T11:37:52.566+0530    connected to: localhost
2015-11-06T11:37:53.159+0530    error inserting documents: lost connection to server
2015-11-06T11:37:53.159+0530    Failed: lost connection to server
2015-11-06T11:37:53.159+0530    imported 0 documents
```

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Please add the output of `netstat -tanp` if on Linux to your question. Alternatively, please add the `bind_address` parameter of your config file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: mongoimport loses connection when importing big files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475505/mongodb-mongoimport-loses-connection-when-importing-big-files)

Answer (score 7):

try adding a -j parameter

```
mongoimport -d blog -c posts -j 4 < posts.json
```

If this does not work, try changing the j value to 8.

This post explains it: 
[MongoDB: mongoimport loses connection when importing big files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475505/mongodb-mongoimport-loses-connection-when-importing-big-files)

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue. I just added --batchSize 1 option. It worked like a charm.

```
mongoimport -d blog -c posts -j 4 < posts.json --batchSize 1
```