# python mongoimport error inserting documents lost connection to server

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I am trying to insert a csv file to mongodb using python os module but i am getting this error:

> 2016-03-02T05:25:23.718+0000  connected to: localhost
>
> 2016-03-02T05:25:23.731+0000  error inserting documents: lost connection to server
>
> 2016-03-02T05:25:23.731+0000   Failed: lost connection to server
>
> 2016-03-02T05:25:23.731+0000   imported 0 documents

My code is :

```
def uploadBulkProducts(self, new_products_file):
    with open('new_products.csv','wb') as new_file:
        for chunk in new_products_file.chunks():
            new_file.write(chunk)

    try:
        os.system("mongoimport --db picknbox --collection temp_products --type csv --file new_products.csv --headerline")
        os.remove('new_products.csv')
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475505/mongodb-mongoimport-loses-connection-when-importing-big-files), [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1033) and [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-939) post. They all say that I should limit the batch size to lesser value than default (10000). But i have only 1 row in my csv file.

My [CSV FILE](http://temp-host.com/download.php?file=xq39ke)

I tried the same from terminal but same. I am using MongoDB version `3.0.9`

EDIT:

I am using django to import a csv file to a mongodb collection. I saved the file to a directory. and then import the file using `mongoimport` command.

I can save the file easily and i can see it in my directory. I confirmed that mongod is running . The error log is from django development server.

This code is working fine in another project running on same versions.

Also when i run the same mongoimport command from terminal i got the exact same error. I ran a read statement side by side in mongo shell and it worked fine.

Comment: *"I tried the same from terminal but same"*, so is `mongod` even running on the same host? You do realize you need to start the server daemon first, don't you?

Comment: I am using ubuntu and yes mongod is running. I can execute my other read or insert statements fine. Only having problem with this one.  I even restarted it to check for any problems but none.

Comment: Where is it happening? When is it happening? More information is needed. On the same host the error suggests that the instance is stopping and surely there are either errors in the console from `mongoimport` or in the server log. Also kind of running off topic since regardless of also attempting to execute with a "system" call from ptyhon, that part really isn't related to the problem here.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSV is in UTF-16 format. On unix, convert the content to allow it as input:

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t ISO-8859-1 new_products.csv \
   | mongoimport --db picknbox --collection temp_products --type csv --headerline
```

So the `iconv` utility will do that for you and you can just pipe the output directly into `mongoimport`, or convert otherwise to a format accepted by `mongoimport`.

Comment: That worked like a charm!! BTW what formats does `mongoimport` supports. In docs for `mongoimport` i cannot see the supported formats.

Comment: @ManishGupta It isn't actually documented, but any of the single byte latin ecodings or UTF-8 ( also single byte ) should be accepted. Anything else would likely cause problems. FYI you could have included the `--verbose` option on `mongoimport`, which would have at least indicated some "funny characters" on parsing the header line that lead to the program exit. The utility could do with a more explicit error message that is also missing.