# Why MongoDB loses connect while importing Larger size files?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I have tried many times and could not understand why importing my 2.72GB file to MongoDB gives me error of connection loss.
Here is what happening:

```
C:\MongoDB\Server\bin>mongoimport -d sis -c alpha --file "C:\Users\lenovo-pc\Desktop\formattejson.json"
2017-01-27T15:08:57.759+0530    connected to: localhost
2017-01-27T15:09:00.753+0530    [########################] sis.alpha    2.72GB/11.7MB (23878.0%)
2017-01-27T15:09:03.753+0530    [########################] sis.alpha    2.72GB/11.7MB (23878.0%)
2017-01-27T15:09:06.753+0530    [########################] sis.alpha    2.72GB/15.7MB (17783.3%)
2017-01-27T15:09:09.753+0530    [########################] sis.alpha    2.72GB/15.7MB (17783.3%)
2017-01-27T15:09:12.753+0530    [########################] sis.alpha    2.72GB/15.7MB (17783.3%)
2017-01-27T15:09:15.754+0530    [########################] sis.alpha    2.72GB/19.7MB (14167.3%)
2017-01-27T15:09:18.753+0530    [########################] sis.alpha    2.72GB/19.7MB (14167.3%)
2017-01-27T15:09:21.753+0530    [########################] sis.alpha    2.72GB/23.7MB (11773.3%)
2017-01-27T15:09:24.753+0530    [########################] sis.alpha    2.72GB/23.7MB (11773.3%)
.
.
.
.
.
.
2017-01-27T15:13:03.753+0530    [########################] sis.alpha    2.72GB/240MB (1162.3%)
2017-01-27T15:13:04.324+0530    [########################] sis.alpha    2.72GB/240MB (1162.3%)
2017-01-27T15:13:04.324+0530    Failed: lost connection to server
2017-01-27T15:13:04.326+0530    imported 1054639 documents
```

The dots (.) means there are other transactions, I have omitted to save space in my question here.

I want to know why is this happening and what I should do to import my file without any error. If there is any workable suggestion please guide me.
Let me tell you that I have already check this question: [MongoDB: mongoimport loses connection when importing big files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475505/mongodb-mongoimport-loses-connection-when-importing-big-files) and the answer available doesn't solve my problem. Please let me know if there is any other possible solution for my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: mongoimport loses connection when importing big files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475505/mongodb-mongoimport-loses-connection-when-importing-big-files)

Comment: @DanFromGermany sir I have already gone through this question but the solution didn't work in my case. Please advise me if there is any other workable solution for the problem.

Comment: You did also try `--batchSize 1` with no change?

Comment: I tried that too `mongoimport -d sis -c alpha --file "C:\Users\lenovo-pc\Desktop\formattejson.json" --batchSize 1` No change. Is this happening because of there is any import limit on mongo DB?