# MongoDB import of geojson data fails

Tags: json, database, mongodb, geojson

I'm trying to import some GeoJson data into MongoDB. The entire file is about 24MB, so in theory the per-document limit of 16MB shouldn't be exceeded. But it looks like it's complaining about the size. I have tried [solutions offered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475505/mongodb-mongoimport-loses-connection-when-importing-big-files), but none seems to work. I type the command:

```
mongoimport -d userdata -c countries < countries.geojson
```

and I get

```
2017-11-17T01:09:29.561+0400    connected to: localhost
2017-11-17T01:09:31.055+0400    num failures: 1
2017-11-17T01:09:31.055+0400    Failed: lost connection to server
2017-11-17T01:09:31.055+0400    imported 0 documents
```

and the mongod logs show (after backtrace):

```
2017-11-17T01:09:31.055+0400 I -        [conn153] AssertionException handling request, closing client connection: 10334 BSONObj size: 17756597 (0x10EF1B5) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: insert: "countries"
2017-11-17T01:09:31.055+0400 I -        [conn153] end connection 127.0.0.1:61806 (2 connections now open)
```

I have tried

```
mongoimport -d userdata -c countries < countries.geojson --batchSize 1
```

and

```
mongoimport -d userdata -c countries -j 4 < countries.geojson
```

based on other similar answers but got the same result, with the same response and logs.

Anyone have clues as to what's going on here? Should I break the GeoJson into two and give that a shot? I thought the 16MB limit was on individual documents, not collections or collection imports.

Comment: `num failures: 1` means your data is malformed. You need to make sure that what you are supplying is actually valid JSON. You possibly might have the data in the file wrapped in an array `[]`. If that is the case then [`--jsonArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-jsonarray) is the option you would be looking for. But basically lint your JSON to ensure it's valid, since `mongoimport` believes it is not. And it's usually right.

Comment: That would make sense, thanks! Giving this a try.