# mongoimport dosent work well on big files

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have a json file of around 4M json lines, I tried to use:

```
mongoimport --db mydb --collection mycoll --file myfile.json
```

and what happened was weird. I got this error:

```
2018-12-29T17:00:50.424+0200    connected to: localhost
2018-12-29T17:00:50.483+0200    Failed: error processing document #1428: invalid character 'S' after object key:value pair
2018-12-29T17:00:50.483+0200    imported 1426 documents
```

so first I went to count this collection in mongo and saw that there are 1000 documents and not 1426 as the above mentioned.

second, I located a json with the `'S'` in it, which is just a string that looks like `"name" : "Double 'S' Transport"` and left only this json in the file, import and it worked well.

does anyone understands why is it happening? my suspicion is that mongoimport dosent work on files that big...

any help would be great :)

Comment: Hope this stack overflow answer helps you [https://stackoverflow.com/a/33561043/5543072](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33561043/5543072)

Comment: There's a known issue with `mongoimport` potentially reporting an incorrect number of documents inserted if a JSON error occurs (see [TOOLS-1811](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-1811) in the MongoDB issue tracker). However, the error message is about an unexpected character in the JSON file you are importing which should be unrelated to the length of the file. You may want to try validating your file with a JSON lint checker. How big are the average JSON documents? What specific versions of `mongoimport` and MongoDB are you using, and what is your O/S version?